# Loading non-power-of-two textures in Vulkan

Tags: c++, image, graphics, vulkan

My 2D texture loader works fine if my texture dimensions are power-of-two, but when they are not, the texture data displays as skewed. How do I fix this? I assume the issue has something to do with memory alignment and row pitch. Here's relevant parts of my loader code:

```
VkMemoryRequirements memReqs;
vkGetImageMemoryRequirements( GfxDeviceGlobal::device, mappableImage, &memReqs );

VkMemoryAllocateInfo memAllocInfo = {};
memAllocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
memAllocInfo.pNext = nullptr;
memAllocInfo.memoryTypeIndex = 0;
memAllocInfo.allocationSize = memReqs.size;

GetMemoryType( memReqs.memoryTypeBits, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT, &memAllocInfo.memoryTypeIndex );

VkDeviceMemory mappableMemory;
err = vkAllocateMemory( GfxDeviceGlobal::device, &memAllocInfo, nullptr, &mappableMemory );
CheckVulkanResult( err, "vkAllocateMemory in Texture2D" );

err = vkBindImageMemory( GfxDeviceGlobal::device, mappableImage, mappableMemory, 0 );
CheckVulkanResult( err, "vkBindImageMemory in Texture2D" );

VkImageSubresource subRes = {};
subRes.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
subRes.mipLevel = 0;
subRes.arrayLayer = 0;

VkSubresourceLayout subResLayout;
vkGetImageSubresourceLayout( GfxDeviceGlobal::device, mappableImage, &subRes, &subResLayout );

void* mapped;
err = vkMapMemory( GfxDeviceGlobal::device, mappableMemory, 0, memReqs.size, 0, &mapped );
CheckVulkanResult( err, "vkMapMemory in Texture2D" );

const int bytesPerPixel = 4;
std::size_t dataSize = bytesPerPixel * width * height;
std::memcpy( mapped, data, dataSize );

vkUnmapMemory( GfxDeviceGlobal::device, mappableMemory );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `VkSubresourceLayout`, which you obtained from `vkGetImageSubresourceLayout` will contain the pitch of the texture in the `rowPitch` member. It's more than likely not equal to the `width`, thus, when you do a `memcpy` of the entire data block, you're copying relevant data into the padding section of the texture.

Instead you will need to `memcpy` row-by-row, skipping the padding memory in the mapped texture:

```
const int bytesPerPixel = 4;
std::size_t dataRowSize = bytesPerPixel * width;
char* mappedBytes = (char*)mapped;
for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
{
    std::memcpy(mapped, data, dataSize);
    mappedBytes += rowPitch;
    data += dataRowSize;
}
```

(this code assumes data is a `char *` as well - its declaration wasn't given)

Comment: Note, that this answer applies not only to NPOT textures, but to all textures. Texture uploads must respect the 'rowPitch' parameter, which may be different on each device.

Comment: @sacygan what if I use vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer? Will the buffer contain padding bytes

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
{
    std::memcpy(mappedBytes, data, dataRowSize);
    mappedBytes += layout.rowPitch;
    data += dataRowSize;
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps?

Comment: I just fixed Muer implementation typo. Solution from him